# Converting tuple of bags to Multiple tuples in pig using a java UDF

Tags: apache-pig

I have my data as:

```
{(2000),(1800),(2700)}
{(2014),(1500),(1900)} etc.
```

I have created a java UDF:

```
DataBag bag = (DataBag) top3.get(0);
Tuple categoryCode = null;
if(bag.size() == 0)
    return null;
for(Iterator<Tuple> code=bag.iterator(); code.hasNext();)
    categoryCode=code.next();
return categoryCode.get(0).toString();
```

I want my output to be like:

```
2000,1800,2700
2014,1500,1900 etc
```

My UDF gives me the output as:

```
2000
2014 etc
```

Please help whether there is some other solution for this. Please help with your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy, look at that:

```
public class YourClass extends EvalFunc<String>{

    @Override
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {

        DataBag bag = (DataBag)input.get(0);

        Tuple categoryCode = null;

        //Keep the count of every cell in the 
        Tuple auxiliary = TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple(3);

        int i = 0;
        for(Iterator<Tuple> code=bag.iterator(); code.hasNext();) {
            categoryCode=code.next();
            //You can use append if don't know from the very beginning
            //the size of tuple
            auxiliary.set(i, categoryCode.get(0).toString());
            i+=1;
        }

        return auxiliary.toDelimitedString(",");
    }   
}
```

You be better of using an auxiliary tuple to do things easier and then just use the instance method `toDelimitedString()`, pretty straightforward.

Comment: another help...can you tell mw how to separate this data into multiple columns? i mean i need 2000,1800,2700 to be in 3 different columns.

Comment: You should then return a tuple in your UDF, instead a String since it returns a tuple with just one field(your string), otherwise, you also could use `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL` to transform it into a 3-sized-tuple, and finally if you don't need this relation to be used any further, you could store as `STORE A INTO 'output' USING PigStorage(',','-noschema');`

Comment: I have tried using REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(my_tuple, '( * )\,( * )'). I am getting an error which says:"ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error at line 24, column 324. Encountered: "," (44), after : "\'( * )\\"". Please help